# Can't import a class in java. Code refuses to believe it exists

Tags: java, class, oop, package

Okay so I made code that wants to find the area of a circle, triangle and square. There are two java files in my package folder, Mung.
 For some reason I keep getting the error
Shapes.java:2: error: package Mung does not exist

Here's my code.

```
import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
import Mung.*;
public class Shapes
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println(areaSquare());
      System.out.println(areaCircle());
      System.out.println(areaTriangle());
   }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
public class ShapesAssignment
{
   public ShapesAssignment (double r,double h,double w)
  {
  double radius = r;
  double height = h;
  double width = w;
  }
   public double areaCircle()
   {
      double cArea = Math.PI * radius;
      return cArea;
   }
   public double areaTriangle()
   {
      double tArea = (height*width)/2;
      return tArea;

    }
    public double areaSquare()
   {
      double sArea = (height*width);
      return sArea;

   }
   public double radius;
   public double height;
   public double width;
}
```

Comment: both Shapes and ShapesAssignment are in the same package? if so, you just need to declare `package Mung;` and not import

Comment: Not  what   you asked, but _please_ don't use asterisks in your `import` statements.  They can [cause your code to fail unexpectedly](http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please take a screenshot of your project tree in eclipse? If Mung is a class, which it looks like it from here, then you do not import it like that. You would import the package in which Mung class is found. If I am misunderstanding it, then that is because you have named your packages incorrectly. It should look something like this:

```
import com.company.app.<name>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IntelliJ or Android Studio, you can try going to Files->Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart.

For any other IDE, you can try clearing the local cache and restarting the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

What is Ming package and do you really need it ?
Lets try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Shapes {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     ShapesAssignment sp = new ShapesAssignment(2, 3, 4);
     System.out.println(sp.areaSquare());
     System.out.println(sp.areaCircle());
     System.out.println(sp.areaTriangle());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting two Java files in the same folder doesn't mean they are in the same package.

Maybe there is really no need to import anything - check, if both of these files (source file of `Mung` and file in which you want to use `Mung`) are in the *default* package (none of these files start with key word  `package`...), you can simply use `Mung` in other files without specifying any import)

If at least one of these files starts with `package` key word, these files are in other packages. You need to make sure that the file you need to import from starts with word `package` (I suppose that `Mung` is not the package but the class - package names start with lower case letter, I think `Mung` is rather a class that you need a method to import from). Check file that contains class you need to import from, if it starts with something like `package mypackage.xyz;`.

If it doesn't start with word `package`, you are not able to import anything from this file with `import` keyword, as everything in this file is in *default* package (Java doesn't allow to import anything contained in *default* package with the use of `import` key word).

If it is in any other package than *default*, import it with the full name of the package and with the name of the class, for example:

```
import mypackage.xyz.Mung.*;
```